# Log in web with urllib2 (python) ! but My code cant do it! Could you fix it for me?

Tags: urllib2, urllib

Log in web with urll

> ib2! but My code cant do it! Could you fix it for me: I wana login
>   website : http://kenhhd.tv/user/login.html

My code is :

```
import urllib,cookielib
import urllib2,re,random,sys,datetime
import mechanize
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'RedditTesting')]

urllib2.install_opener(opener)
link_login = "http://kenhhd.tv/user/login.html?fast=true"
payload = {
    'email': 'my_email@yahoo.com',
    'password': 'my_pass'
    }
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
req = urllib2.Request(link_login,data)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
contents = resp.read()
log = re.search(r'Tran the vinh',contents)
if log:
    print "log-in is ok"
else:
    print "erro"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Python-Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) which can automatically handle cookies (through Sessions), here's an example :

```
from requests import Session

s = Session() # create a new Session which will handle the cookies

s.headers["User-Agent"] = "RedditTesting" # you wanted a custom user-agent, so here it is, it'll get applied to each request made with that session object

payload = {
    "email":"email@domain.tld",
    "password":"ExamplePassword",
    "remember":"on", # additional parameters that I saw on the login page and may be needed
    "_submit":"true" # same as above
}

r = s.post("http://kenhhd.tv/user/login.html", payload) # make the request

if "Tran the vinh" in r.text: # no need for regex if you just want to check if a string is in another string
    print "logged in successfully"
else:
    print "could not log in, something went wrong"
```

Comment: I cant login with that form.. Andre! could you help me! I dont see Tran the vinh in r.text